# JS events source detection

Tags: javascript

I'm working on a part of my web site where people can vote on publications, I have many in the same page, and next every publication there are two images one to agree and the other to disagree. I want to change the images, so when someone votes, whether agree or not, the image changes to say he already voted.
Here's my code:

JPS:

```
<logic:iterate id="comment" name="Liste_Comments" scope="request">   
<html:img  src="pages/images/ok.png" alt="Vote pour!" paramId="code" paramName="comment"   paramProperty="code" onclick="voterComment('pour');"/> 

<html:img  src="pages/images/ko.png" alt="Vote contre!" paramId="code" paramName="comment"  paramProperty="code" onclick="voterComment('contre');"/>       

       <bean:write name="comment" property="libelle" />       
       <bean:write name="comment" property="subject" /> 
       <br>       
</logic:iterate>
```

Script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            function voterComment(vote) {            
                var url = "<%=request.getContextPath()%>/VoteComment.do";
                new Ajax.Request(url, {
                    parameters: {vote: vote},
                    onSuccess: function(transport, json) {
                        if (json.error) {
                            alert(json.error);
                        }
                        else{
                            window.event.srcElement.src = "pages/images/photo.jpg";
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
   </script>
```

I have a problem to access to the image that was clicked!!

Thanks guys, in advance, for your great helping :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change you html to send the value of `this` to the click handler.  This will contain a reference to the source element - in this case the image that was clicked.

```
<html:img ...  paramProperty="code" onclick="voterComment(this, 'pour');"/>
```

Javascript:

```
function voterComment(sourceImage , vote) {       
   var url = "<%=request.getContextPath()%>/VoteComment.do";
   new Ajax.Request(url, {
       parameters: {vote: vote},
       onSuccess: function(transport, json) {
          if (json.error) {
              alert(json.error);
          }
          else{
              sourceImage.src = "pages/images/photo.jpg";
          }
       }
   });
}
```

Comment: ok let me try that out, I'm not supposed to install something else to see the result!!